# How to fetch month and year at the same time from date where date column is in varchar datatype. Using snowflake tool

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch both the months and years from the Column (MISSUE) while introducing an "_"  in snowflake. For example (6_2021, 7_2021 etc).

This can be archive in MS Access query as:

Month([MISSUE]) & "_" & Year([MISSUE]) AS Month_Year

My current Code in Snowflake shows:

EXTRACT(Month, TO_DATE(MISSUE)) &'_'& EXTRACT(Year, TO_DATE(MISSUE)) AS Month_Year

Can someone please tell me what I am during wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't think Snowflake uses the & operator to combine strings. Use || instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT_WS()` for this.

```
with tbl as (select $1 as MISSUE from values ('2017-04-10'), ('2017-06-10'))

select concat_ws('_', month(to_date(MISSUE)), year(to_date(MISSUE))) from tbl;

CONCAT_WS('_', MONTH(TO_DATE(MISSUE)), YEAR(TO_DATE(MISSUE)))
4_2017
6_2017
```

Comment: I have an error: Can't parse '2017-04-10' as date with format 'MM_YYYY'

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively save yourself some typing (dad joke) :

```
select to_char(MISSUE::DATE,'MM_YYYY') from tbl
```

[image]

Copy|Paste|Run|In Snowflake:

```
with tbl as (select $1 as MISSUE from values ('2017-04-10'), ('2017-06-10'))
select
    to_char(MISSUE :: DATE, 'MM_YYYY') cleaner
from
     tbl
```